# 405 (Method not allowed) in angular2/4

Tags: angular

```
updateUserDetails(ename,ejobtitle,edept,eunit,equal,eaqser,empid)
{

  let url = GlobalVariable.BASE_API_URL + "api/updateUserProfile";    
  let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type':'application/json'});
  let options = new RequestOptions({headers:headers});
  const body = 
  {"empno":empid,"name":ename,"jobtitle":ejobtitle,"dept":edept,"unit":eunit,"qualification":equal,"aqinservice":eaqser}

  return this.http.post(url,body,options)
  .map(resp=>resp.json());    

}
```

API

```
[Route("api/updateUserProfile")]
    [HttpPost]       
    public HttpResponseMessage updateUserProfile(HttpResponseMessage Req)
    {
        try
        {
            string postData = new System.IO.StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();

            UserMaster.Instance.UpdateUserProfile(postData);
            var JSONString = new StringBuilder();
            JSONString.Append("{");
            JSONString.Append("\"status" + "\":" + "\"ok" + "\",");
            JSONString.Append("\"message" + "\":" + "\"Record Updated successfilly." + "\"");              
            JSONString.Append("}");
            var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            response.Content = new StringContent(JSONString.ToString(), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            return response;

        }
}
```

---

I am getting error in angular 4 - 405 (Method Not allowed)

But it works perfectly in Fiddler.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve... Also provide a full error traceback.

Comment: @johnashu That is a suggested course. Sometimes it is not possible to provide those things due to code that is proprietary or that requires a lot of extraneous code not relevant to the problem, or when you don't know where the problem lies. "When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, *you will get much better answers*" <- means that answers are possible, but will be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There exist a lot of ways to do this, one of it is you can use Object.keys() and Object.values() method to extract keys and values from your data.

```
      keys:Array<String>;
      values:Array<String>;
    item={"em id":"101","name":"ABC","role":"admin"};

 myFun()
    {
     this.keys=Object.keys(this.item);
      this.values=Object.values(this.item);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The most simplest way to use that object is to just give it a name and access its properties.

example ,

```
item = {"em id":"101","name":"ABC","role":"admin"};
```

and then using it like this ,

```
console.log("em_id is " + item.em_id + "name is " + item.name + "role is" + item.role );
```

But if you really want to store it in variable then just do it in same way ,

```
let em_id = item.em_id;
let name = item.name;
let role = item.role;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the "**preflight request**". Adding the OPTIONS method to your api and then just return should work.